Examples of $\mathbb{N}$-graded algebras whose global dimension is strictly less than the GK dimension
The relationship between the global and GK dimensions of Artin-Schelter regular algebras remains to be mysterious, yet both dimensions are conjectured to be equal.
In a more broad setting, are there any known examples of connected $\mathbb{N}$-graded algebras of finite global and GK dimensions such that the global dimension is strictly less than the GK dimension?
If such examples exist, I hope to gain insights by studying their projective resolutions and Hilbert series, and to explore how these insights might apply to the study of Artin-Schelter regular algebras. Thank you for any information or references you may have!

The Weyl algebra has global dimension 1 and GK dimension 2. It is trivially $\mathbb{N}$-graded by putting the whole algebra in degree 0. I think you may want to assume the algebras are connected graded.

@J.Gaddis Thank you for pointing that out! I'm indeed interested in examples of connected $\mathbb{N}$-graded algebras. I've edited my post to reflect that.
